# Disambiguate the [doomsday] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Earlier I spotted the [doomsday](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doomsday) tag and the broad range of things it's used to mean:

- [Doomsday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_(Doctor_Who)), the second season finale of the Doctor Who reboot  in **[Doomsday - How Does Pete Know](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66785/28162)**
- [doomsday](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doomsday), the end of the world, in **[What is the extent and nature of Nix's power in (the film) Lord of Illusions?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64041/28162)**
- [Doomsday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_%28comics%29), the DC Comics character and antagonist of Superman in **[If Doomsday was so powerful, why couldn't he get out of his restraints?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20594/28162)**

Obviously, these are all perfectly valid claims for the tag, but the wide range of uses also makes it far too broad to put under a single tag.

**What should we do with these questions and the tag to make it more useful?**

Comment: I disagree that they're all valid claims. We don't have tags for every single character in a series, only the main ones. Nor do we have tags for specific episodes of a long running series. Personally I would have edited those questions and removed the tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per Moogle's comment, I think the tag doesn't belong on the *Doctor Who* question, since we normally wouldn't tag each and every episode of a TV series. So I removed it.

In the question about Nix's power, the tag is only tangentially related. So I removed it.
The concept of a doomsday, the end of the world, can be covered be other concepts as well. I think that (if we ever actually need one) [end-of-the-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/end-of-the-world) or something similar would cover it better, without being tied to s specific term.

So that leaves the character Doomsday. While there's only one question about Doomsday tagged as such, a simple search showed more examples. So those could be tagged [doomsday](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doomsday), and if we keep the tag, I feel it should be about the character.

Comment: I don't know what search terms you used, but when I used the search "doomsday is:question" I couldn't find any questions that needed the tag beyond the 2 that are currently tagged with it.